# Is it possible to use Java as a scripting language?

Tags: c++, java, scripting

Is it possible to use Java as a scripting language for a C++ engine/game?

I understand that you need to make a binding to the interpreter, but I haven't seen any around.

Comment: It's more common to use something that is designed to be a scripting language, like Javascript, or Lua, or Python.

Comment: If you really want to use Java, the best approach would be probably the opposite, call a C++ engine FROM your Java code

Comment: It is possible but for me the question remains "Why" would you ever use a language with the same complexity for scripting as for the engine? Normally you use a scripting languare that is Much more simple than C++ or Java because you can controle it better and a 'not really a programmer' can make marvels with it!

Comment: @Valmond Why? For Speed!

Comment: Then go with C# or even better, C++ ;-) IIRC Lua is quite fast, Python too.

Comment: @Valmond ok then :D

Comment: @Valmond
>Lua
>fast
Please choose one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quite possible.

You could probably use the [GNU Interpreter for Java](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Interpreter_for_Java) or some other such system.  However I think you'll find a lot more cases (as mentioned above) of people using Lua, Python or other languages in games.  Lua in particular is very well suited for the task of embedded scripting.

Additionally, you might check [the jog interpreter](http://code.google.com/p/jog-interpreter/) project, which touts itself as, "...a lightweight but reasonably full-featured and fast Java compiler and interpreter." that is written in C++.

Amusingly, googling for "java interpreters in C++" seems to yield as many (if not more) hits for C++ interpreters written in Java instead of the other way around :)

Answer (score 5):

Yes, it's possible. Way back in 1999, an article was published in [Game Developer](http://www.gdmag.com/) on the subject, entitled "Dirty Java: Using the JNI Within Games." I still have my copy of issue in fact. Fortunately [the article also appears to be available online](http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/3347/dirty_java_using_the_java_native_.php?print=1). Of course, the code in that article is probably a tad out of date, so you can also check out these articles as well:

- [JNI – C++ integration made easy](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/~gabr/papers/cuj_jni.pdf)
- [How to Call Java Functions from C using JNI](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/CJniJava.aspx)

However, these days it's probably better to consider a language like Python, Lua or Javascript for your embedding needs. They're a lot more lightweight and, in the case of Lua in particular, designed with embedding and scripting in mind.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. Game Vampire the Masquerade - Redemption uses Java as a scripting language. And that game is the only serious game i know of using Java. Bear i mind, they are not using Java for their Nod engine.

Edit:
There is JMonkeyEngine written completely in Java.

Comment: Java was considered as an option for Quake 2 way back in 1997: http://www.team5150.com/~andrew/carmack/johnc_plan_1997.html#d19970313

Answer (score 2):

Bohemia Interactive (BIS) has announced that Arma3 will use Java as its scripting language.  BIS will be introducing their Java scripting engine in the [next patch for Take On Helicopters](http://forums.bistudio.com/showthread.php?t=128800).

Answer (score 1):

MMORPG [Darkfall Online](http://www.darkfallonline.com/) uses Java as a scripting engine.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible.

However if you are looking for a JVM langauge for scripting, I'd probably recommend either Clojure or Groovy over Java itself - both are dynamic langauges that are better suited for the interactive development style that you usually want with scripting langauges.

Answer (score 0):

It definitely is possible, but Java isn't the best language to use for scripting, as a language it was designed with the goal of actually being used to write the core application itself, not for the scripting in the application.